# How to access Everyone But External Users via Javascript in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, permissions

When adding a group to a site via Javascript, I know you're supposed to use the group ID - but if I want to add "Everyone except external users" to that site with Read permissions, what ID do you use? I'm building a utility page to update all the sites on our portal that used to have "NT Authority/Authenticated Users" permissions but lost that group when the site migrated. Can you apply the "Everyone except" group by name, or is there some other specific way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The group id you are looking for is called `spo-grid-all-users`.  The full claim that is resolved is `c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/11111111-A111-1A11-A111-1AAA1A111111`.

In the claim above the sequence `11111111-A111-1A11-A111-1AAA1A111111` represents a User GUID specific to that user and your tenant.
To obtain your tenant specific GUID for this user / claim navigate to:

`https://YourTenantPrefix.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`

Be sure to replace the YourTenantPrefix portion of the URL above with Your Tenant Prefix.

The query string ***?MembershipGroupId=0*** will display all users in your tenant including the tenant specific, system created ones including:  Everyone, Everyone Except External Users, and the Search Crawler